# How to find and extract position of a value in two dimentional array in Excel

Tags: excel

I have 2D array from which I have to find the 50 largest values and to create one dimensional array. Also, I have to find the position of these values and extract the data from the rows and the columns - the date and the hour.

[image: excel sheet]

I used `LARGE` function to find the 50 largest values but need to extract also the date (row) and the hour (column) from the array.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome!
Please share some code of what you're trying to do and what isn't working for you

Comment: I want to find the 50 largest values from the array which I have alredy done with LARGE function. But I also have to identify the position of these values in the array - row and column. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are able to find the Large(k) number, I am going to start my solution from finding the row and column for each Large(k) number.

Lets consider the below sample data.
[image: Sample data]

Formula used for Date row

```
=INDEX(A2:A6,LET(x,(B2:E6=C7)*SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:A6)),MIN(IF(x>0,x))))
```

Formula used for Hr Column

```
=INDEX(B1:E1,,LET(x,(B2:E6=C7)*SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(B1:E1)),MIN(IF(x>0,x))))
```

Comment: Thank you sir! That was exactly what i needed!

Comment: There is a problem with the TEXTJOIN function which is limited to 252 arguments. Mine's are 12 000.

Comment: I am not using textjoin function

Comment: @DimitarGeorgiev What does `TEXTJOIN` have to do with your problem or this answer?

Comment: I figured it out! Job done! Thank you again!